# JScrollPane not scrolling in JTextArea and is staying disabled

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am trying to make a simple text editor using JTextArea, but when I type more text so that it goes off the screen, the JScrollPane is still not enabled and not letting me to scroll. I've looked for hours for answers on the internet but nothing seemed to help me.
Here is my code:

```java
import mods.JFrame.JFrameMods;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NimbleIDE {
    
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea main;
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main);
    
    NimbleIDE() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        main = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(main);
        
        //Frame setting up
        initialiseBlankJFrame(frame, "NimbleIDE");
        frame.add(scroll);
        
        //Text setting up
        main.setSize(JFrameMods.getScreenWidth() - 14, JFrameMods.getScreenHeight()); //JFrameMods is a custom class I made previously
        main.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        main.setLineWrap(true);
        main.setEditable(true);
        
        //Scroll setting up
        scroll.setBounds(JFrameMods.getScreenWidth() - 14, 0, 16, JFrameMods.getScreenHeight() - 23);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
    }
    
    initialiseBlankJFrame(JFrame frame, String title) {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setTitle(title);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try to add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your further posts. I had to substantially modify your code so it compiled and executed on my computer.

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers 2) components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is packed and made visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
JTextArea main;
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main);
```

effectively means this:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(null);
```

You're passing a `null` object to the `JScrollPane`.

---

You can fix your problem by passing an actual `JTextArea` object to your scroll pane. Also note that the scroll pane is the only component that you explicity have to add to your `JFrame`. Something like this:

```
public class NimbleIDE {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea main;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    
    NimbleIDE() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        main = new JTextArea();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(main);

        //Frame setting up
        initialiseBlankJFrame(frame, "NimbleIDE");
        frame.add(scroll);

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

You may also want to take a look at the following Java Trails:

- [How to Use Scroll Panes (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning) (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Laying Out Components Within a Container)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)